# Display image from MYSQL using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, html

Having trouble seeing the image on my webpage.  I verified that the image was inserted correctly by exporting the blob field to a jpg file and viewing it.

Here is my code.  Why Cannot I see the image on my webpage ?

```
$mysql2 = "SELECT pfilename,actual_img from brigpics where pfilename = '".$flist."'";
$stmt = $db1->prepare($mysql2);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindColumn(1, $pfname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $actual_img, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $actual_img;
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information on the matter? How is the image stored in the database, link form?

Comment: Image is stored as a longblob

Comment: The Default charset is uft8

Comment: $fhandle = fopen($dirname.$flist,'rb');
        $file_content = fread($fhandle,filesize($dirname.$flist));

        $msql = "INSERT INTO BRIGPICS (pfilename,dispname, actual_img, foldername) VALUE (:pfilename,:dispname,:actual_img,:foldername)";

        $q =  $db1->prepare($msql);

        $q->bindparam(':pfilename',  $flist);
        $q->bindparam(':dispname',   $flist);
        $q->bindparam(':actual_img', $fhandle, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $q->bindparam(':foldername', $dirname);
        $q->execute();
        fclose($fhandle);